# Which registry keys need to be edited to change the default browser?

Tags: windows, browser, windows-registry

Which registry keys need to be edited to change the default browser?

I have found these keys so far and they seem to do what I want, but I am not sure if I have found all of them:

Data in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\http\shell\open\command
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\https\shell\open\command
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ftp\shell\open\command
```

Value in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache
```

Are there any other keys which would need to be changed, so that it is done perfectly?

Comment: A very comprehensive article about your question: [How Does Your Browser Know that It’s Not The Default?](http://newoldthing.wordpress.com/2007/03/23/how-does-your-browsers-know-that-its-not-the-default-browser/)

Comment: @Mehper: Thanks.  It looks like I have got them the right locations, other than the local filetypes, as Cosmin mentioned.

Comment: -1 You’re not supposed to be changing the default browser. This is something to be done by the end user.

Comment: I would make a registry backup and then change my browser, make another registry back up and use http://www.grigsoft.com/download-windiff.htm to compare them.

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354861/how-to-find-the-default-browser-via-the-registry-on-windows-10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each browser sets its own registry entries. But you can try finding the common ones by comparing the REG files in these forum threads:

- http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/170215-46-default-browser-registry
- http://forums.techarena.in/technology-internet/1112113.htm

It looks like you missed some registry keys (.html, .htm, gopher etc.).

Comment: Thanks.  I doubt any modern browsers still have any `gopher://` support!

Answer (score 14):

You don’t edit the registry manually. You execute the command specified by the browser creator in the key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\[BROWSER NAME.EXE]\InstallInfo`, value `ReinstallCommand`.

For example, for MSIE it’s `"C:\Windows\System32\ie4uinit.exe" -reinstall`, and for Firefox it is `"X:\path\to\Firefox\uninstall\helper.exe" /SetAsDefaultAppGlobal`.

Comment: Also, it seems that most reliable way to find out default browser is to query `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet` (notice HKCU instead of HKLM) and check the value. It will be `IEXPLORE.EXE`, `FIREFOX.EXE`, `Google Chrome`, `Chromium.SOMERANDOMSTRING` or `OperaStable` for the most popular browsers. This is more reliable than looking at `HKCU\\Software\\Classes\\http\\shell\\open\\command` because IE on Windows 7 doesn't seem to change that setting when you click "make default browser".

Comment: @jakub.g The commands i posted are for HKLM. Never, ever, try to change the HKCU entries programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

> Which registry keys need to be edited to change the default browser?
>   I have found these keys so far and they seem to do what I want, but I am not sure if I have found all of them…

You haven’t; you forgot `.html` files, `.htm` files, `.url` bookmarks, and so on.

The fact is that a browser is much like a media player. There is no single “default media-player” setting; rather there are separate and individual file-associations for each file-type and protocol that the media-player supports. The same goes for browser; there is no single “default browser” setting; only associations for each type it supports.

In the case of browsers, they usually support, at a minimum, `.html` and `.htm` files, `.url` bookmarks, and `http`, `https`, and `ftp` protocols.

> I doubt any modern browsers still have any gopher:// support!

Says who? A browser could easily support the gopher protocol and archie and magnet links and emule links and `.torrent` files and `.svg` files and `.mp4` files and Flash files and so on and so on.

To properly set a browser as “the default”, it has to be associated with each file-type and protocol that it supports (or at the very least, each one that you intend to use it with).

Comment: Gopher is/was nothing like a file type or a protocol link that would execute another program.  It was a completely different form of browsing servers.  All the mainstream browsers have long dropped support as far as I know.

Comment: @paradroid, actually, a [link format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gopher_(protocol)#URL_links) *was* created, but it was too late by then because it had mostly fallen out of usage, but not completely; Lynx still supports it, and there’s no reaon that any given browser *couldn’t* support it (or any other obscure file-type or protocol for that matter).

Comment: My original comment about gopher support was about actually using it within the browser. When I was first using the internet at university, using Mosaic and later Netscape, there was a lot more content through gopher than than the new 'World Wide Web'.

Answer (score -1):

You can change default browser with with .bat and .vbs file.

There is a code to make:
- IE Default browser for WIN10

===IE_Microsoft_DefaultPrograms.bat===

```
@echo off
cls
echo   --==**##  IE default browser ##**==--
REM Run GUI
cscript //NoLogo IEdefault.vbs
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
echo Done
```

===IEdefault.vbs===

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' IE Default browser for WIN10
WshShell.Run "%windir%\system32\control.exe /name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms /page pageDefaultProgram\pageAdvancedSettings?pszAppName=Internet%20Explorer"

' Give Default Programs time to load
WScript.Sleep 2000

' WshShell.AppActivate "Set Program Associations"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys " "
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys " "

Msgbox "Default browser is Internet Explorer."

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: "In Windows 10 you can not directly edit registry" Huh. Where does this come from? Can you provide a reference?

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. The question has nothing to do with Adobe Reader.

Comment: You were twice right. I removed code about how to Make Adobe Reader the default owner of PDF files on Windows 10.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you check

`HKey_Local_Machine\Software\Classes\http\shell\open\command`

That's where mine was set wrong.