# In Windows XP, how may I change the default browser from chrome to IE on the command line, without admin privs?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, batch-file, windows-xp, command-line

**Situation:**
 1. Need to Set the default browser **to IE via cmd**(problem)
 2. Need to do a Citrix login via IE(amounts to loading a url) because it
    wont run in Google Chrome
 3. then set default browser to Chrome

**Environment:**
  Windows XP, no admin privileges
  no admin privileges mean **I can't touch registry**

**Basic Steps I'm Doing:**
In a bat file:
1. Set default browser to IE
2. Run a Citrix SSO login via IE (not compatible with chrome)
3. Set default browser to Chrome
4. Kill IE
5. Live long and prosper

So I have it all running except **"Set default browser to IE"**

I can set the default browser to Chrome by using Portable Chrome's command line argument 
--make-default-browser

but I can't undo that process.

If I launch IE, it pops up that 'make ie default browser' window which stops the SSO process.

So If I can disable that check via bat file, that would also work for me.

**Things i've tried that didn't work:**
*shmgrate.exe OCInstallReinstallIE*

We are using IE8.

Maybe someone can find a Chrome switch that undoes default browser, a la:
http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: shmgrate.exe OCInstallReinstallIE- which didn't work maybe because its IE8 or I don't have priv's to change anything in internet options, but google chrome does somehow.  If I can find a way to  uninstall chrome as deafult using a chome swtich that might no it but can't find one http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: this may give you clues to where to look: http://superuser.com/questions/287313/which-registry-keys-need-to-be-edited-to-change-the-default-browser

Comment: Probably portable Internet Explorer is solution. But need add code to script for attach portable IE process. But i dont have idea what citrix SSO is it and dont want know it:)

Comment: Does iexplore have to be the default browser? Isn't it possible to just run "start iexplore http: //citrix/login/page/here"

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using one of the following:

- [IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en)
- [IE Tab Seamless](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab-seamless/gnkgjopofhfmjebcalbjlcfilnipmopd?hl=en)
- [IE Tab Multi](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab-multi-enhance/fnfnbeppfinmnjnjhedifcfllpcfgeea?hl=en)

All of these are chrome extension that allow IE compatibility mode. You can set up specific addresses or domains (also using wildcards) to trigger compatibility mode.

This would allow you to stick to only one browser, avoid fiddling the registry and save you from potential problems with unauthorized access.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the window.

screenshot:

internet options > programs > tell me if IE is not default browser
[image: option]

which means this option is stored in the registry. im not going to discuss modifying registry data here, as it is dangerous. but you can do a quick search to find out how.

you can use [reg](http://commandwindows.com/reg.htm).

there is another stackoverflow post that can answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222367/windows-registry-key-for-check-whether-ie-is-the-default-browser

Comment: @Bugmage as i said, its in the registry: from command line you can do: http://commandwindows.com/reg.htm

Comment: as long as python is installed, yes.

Comment: ok so its 100% reg only solution for this then?  Ill relook into it, as I was denied launching .reg files, but I might be able to take a reg snapshot, and code that into a bat file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, by using the `reg` command in Windows as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684849/batch-default-browser).

Specifically you can add this to your `bat` file:

```
REG ADD HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htmlfile\shell\open\command /v (Default)    /t REG_SZ  /d  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -nohome
```

Comment: That only associates it with `.html` files. What about `.htm` files? What about `.url` files? What about `http` addresses? This answer demonstrates the problem with doing things manually: it can be incomplete and you can miss a *lot*.