# Portable browser as default browser in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, browser, portable

Is there any way to make a portable browser the default browser of Windows 8.1? Apparently the registry tricks of Windows 7 are not working in Windows 8 and 8.1!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/287313/which-registry-keys-need-to-be-edited-to-change-the-default-browser

Comment: I also have no problem in windows 7. My question is about windows 8 and 8.1!

Answer (score 0):

You can make so without hassling all those techy registry tricks. 
Most modern browsers have ability to make it default.

For example for Google Chrome go to

> Settings -> Default browser --> Make Google Chrome the default browser

and it will do everything for you.

Actually, my case is Windows 7. And it's annoying to be unable to open links in a default browser, when your browsers are portable.

When i fix my Windows 8.1, i can tell about it, too. May be i am wrong about Windows 8(.1). But it shouldn't differ too much, may be some latest portable browser of choice version could help.

If it won't just try several browsers, and at least one would fit.
All browser's developers couldn't be wrong about not been able to set several registry values according to their product.

Comment: @ Ramhound - yes, i did it by myself yesterday, my Version 56.0.2924.76 (well, not the latest one, but not too old). After that Windows programs start open pages with it according to clicking links. 
Not verified it yet with other browsers, but Firefox for example, does have the same functionality. You may try and tell us.
Ohhh, yes, i see, my case is Windows 7. When i fix my Windows 8.1, i can tell, too. May be i am wrong about Windows 8(.1). But it shouldn't differ too much, may be some latest portable browser of choice version could help.

Comment: Anyway, all browser's developers couldn't be wrong. Just try several browsers, and at least one would fit. 
Added to my answer.

Comment: @ Ramhound As i did tell, it was from portable installation of Chrome, which i'm a bit lazy to update for some time, as portable version can't update automatically.

Comment: @ Ramhound added to my answer. No problem with the question been a bit dated, i did face the very same question just recently, and i believe many people will do. When i try to google it out, i met mainly just registry tricks, which get old very quickly, time consuming and very error-prone.

Comment: @ Ramhound If you try my answer and succeed, i believe your score to my answer would change sign from "-" to "+". )

Comment: As I promised I reversed my vote.  I encourage you to clean up the comments.

Comment: @ Ramhound I guess as i polished it according to your questions, you liked it now. Cleaning comments is not a problem.