# Set Firefox as Standard Browser via Powershell

Tags: firefox, powershell, group-policy

I'm currently creating a deployment image (Win 10 x64). Since I have to use a FOG-Server, I created an Install-user with my powershell script in autostart. The user will be deleted after the script has been executed.
Script is working, however, the customer requires Firefox as Standard Browser. As mentioned I'm using an install user, so I can't go over registry and use the HKCU keys. Also, the tablets won't join a domain.

I thought about a local GPO, but I got no experiences in doing so. I saw [this](https://superuser.com/a/1009244/613662) but I don't know where the command has been executed.

Does anyone have any idea, how I could manage this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Not-so-recent Windows updates now prevent a program to set itself as default for anything, so the snippet below won't work anymore. Thanks to [janv8000](https://superuser.com/users/106793/janv8000) for pointing it out.

---

The command you mention has to be run by the user who needs Firefox as default browser. You can create a batch file and put it in the startup folder of the user's Start menu, making sure it's a self-deleting file. It should look like:

```
@echo off
firefox.exe -silent -nosplash -setDefaultBrowser
erase %0
```

(obviously you can add more commands as needed)

Otherwise, the `Start-process` powershell cmdlet has a `-Credentials` parameter, but from what I see it will prompt you for a password (not suited for a script).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
However, it doesn't seem to be an favourable way since I'm creating the user within the script and thus, they won't have a folder.

Comment: Wait to see if it work before thanking me ^^

Comment: I forgot to shift enter. This solution won't work for me. It must be within a powershell script.

Comment: Then you can try `Start-process` with the crendentials argument, I think I saw a convoluted way to use it without a prompt (creating variables with the name & password of the user). I'm not sure though, it needs confirmation.

Comment: My boss just called me and said this isn't necessary anymore (thank god). however, thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your work.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore, Windows 10 version 1703 and FF 57.0. It just brings up the "Choose default app" UI.

Comment: Where is this startup folder you mention?